# Mongoose Exclude document results at schema level

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongoose, nosql

I am creating a model for my users. Each user has a property `isVerified` which is a boolean. I want to be able to call `Model.find` on the mongoose model and exclude all documents with `isVerified === false` without having to specify this during the query.
I want to set it in the schema such that whenever `Model.find` is called those documents are automatically excluded. Any help is appreciated

User model:

```
const UserSchema:Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        index: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (value:string) => validator.isEmail(value),
            message: (props:any) => "Invalid Email Address"
        },
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        select: false,
        minlength: 6,
        validate: {
            validator: (value:string) => !validator.contains(value, "password"),
            message: (props:any) => "Your password cannot contain the word 'password'"
        }
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (value:string) => validator.isMobilePhone(value, 'any', {strictMode: true}),
            message: (props:any) => "Please include country code (e.g. +233 for Ghana +44 for the United Kingdom) to phone number"
        }
    },
    isActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
    ,
    tokens: [
        {
            token: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ]
},{
    strict: "throw",
    timestamps: true
})
```

Edit:

I did some digging around and it appears I can overwrite the base methods to reimplement the query returned. I attempted to this is as seen below :

```
UserSchema.statics.find = function () {
    let query = UserModel.find.apply(this, arguments);
    query.where('isActive').ne(false)
    return query;
}
```

However I obtain the following error

```
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Needed to apply the change to the `Model` object and not the instance `UserModel` as seen below:

```
UserSchema.statics.find = function () {
    let query = Model.find.apply(this, arguments);
    query.where('isActive').ne(false)
    return query;
}
```

Now the find method skips inactive users